# Angular.js filter to add class to specific items in list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

How do you create a (custom) filter that doesn't remove items from a ng-repeat list but rather adds classes to the items that (don't) match the expression? Or would you rather go for a service based approach?

Comment: A filter is used to transform some data into something else. Adding CSS classes is not what filters are for. Use a directive. Or just use the standard directive to do that: ngClass: `<div ng-class="{selected: item.shouldBeSelected}">`